# Algorithm of blending 'One OneMinusSrcAlpha'

Tags: unity-game-engine, rust, blend, blending

I'm trying to find the algorithm of this blending in rust.
When searching through the [image](https://crates.io/crates/image) crate source, the blending method used is 'src-over' or 'SrcAlpha InvSrcAlpha' if I'm correct: [source](https://github.com/image-rs/image/blob/7bdf398bcf55ca34851376cd9bd78231fc204610/src/color.rs#L730).

So the only thing I need to change is the source factor, from SrcAlpha to One.

[Unity doc](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-Blend.html) say: "The value of this input is one. Use this to use the value of the source or the destination color."

So only use the source value without mult.

I tried to change that:

```rust
let (bg_r_a, bg_g_a, bg_b_a) = (bg_r * bg_a, bg_g * bg_a, bg_b * bg_a);
let (fg_r_a, fg_g_a, fg_b_a) = (fg_r * fg_a, fg_g * fg_a, fg_b * fg_a);
```

to

```rust
let (bg_r_a, bg_g_a, bg_b_a) = (bg_r * bg_a, bg_g * bg_a, bg_b * bg_a);
let (fg_r_a, fg_g_a, fg_b_a) = (fg_r * 1., fg_g * 1., fg_b * 1.);
```

[Here's an example result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oCeKE.jpg)

The 'expected' is in fact not the exact result that i want but very close. I got it from a manual unmultiply alpha, and manual color boost (multiply each channel by 5).

When debugging the blend function I noticed that r,g,b overflow the range of the color (more that 1.0), which make the result image white. and alpha channel remain very very low.

So is the algorithm correct?
Otherwise the issue come from my source.

Comment: "_The output i'm looking for is not good_" → can you give us an example of input, the output you're getting and the output you expected to get for that input?

Comment: Done, but i'm not sure it's gonna help much for my question. I can't give the source image because it is built from an atlas, but they are black and white.
The pipeline is "Crop an atlas" -> "tint it with a color that come from an external file" -> "Blend with other part"

Comment: Ok i think i got it.
I have a base image where i put all the built atlas on it, my process was to build the atlas appart and then overlay it the the main base image. By doing that the first blending start with an rgba destination of 0,0,0,0 and it end up with low a low rgba.
I tried to add a fixed background color before building the atlas and the color poped out correctly.